# ScheduledAgent and GeoCoordinateWatcher - how to make them work?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to get GPS position via GeoCoordinateWatcher running in ScheduledAgent. Unfortunately only location I get is some old one, recorded when application was running. How to get current (latest) location in ScheduledAgent?

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same problem.  Unfortunaty, this is intended behaviour according to the WP7.1 APIs

According to the documentation, "This API, used for obtaining the geographic coordinates of the device, is supported for use in background agents, but it uses a cached location value instead of real-time data. The cached location value is updated by the device every 15 minutes."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: I was testing this feature for about an hour and position changed only once.

Comment: @batman If you were testing for an hour, at best, your scheduled task would run three times (start of hour, mid hour, end of hour) as they are ["about" every thirty minutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). In addition, the location information may be up to 15 minutes old, so it is quite possible that everything was working for you.

Answer (score -2):

My 2 Centlys.

it is probably becoz the GeoCoordinateWatcher takes some time (2 seconds or so) to get the new coordinate values and to lock to GPS or Cellular Mast or Wifi or whatever. And it will give you the last recordered position in the meantime.

So, try to hook to the following events

```
 watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler< GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);

 watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler< GeoPositionChangedEventArgs< GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
```

where watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);

and call the NotifyComplete(); in your "watcher_PositionChanged" event handler.

Comment: It doesn't work either. I'm starting to believe that it isn't possible.