# Geolocator in ScheduledAgent does not work

Tags: windows-phone-8

Geolocator in ScheduledAgent  always give me old value position:
var position = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
this position will always be the same.
It was similar question - [ScheduledAgent and GeoCoordinateWatcher - how to make them work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542249/scheduledagent-and-geocoordinatewatcher-how-to-make-them-work)
But it is too old, may there are some changes.

Comment: It's old, but it's still valid, I'm afraid: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_NoteworthyAPIsforUsewithScheduledTasks

Comment: possible duplicate of [GeoCoordinateWatcher can't give live status or permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455646/geocoordinatewatcher-cant-give-live-status-or-permission)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_NoteworthyAPIsforUsewithScheduledTasks

GeoCoordinateWatcher:

This API, used for obtaining the geographic coordinates of the device, is supported for use in **background agents**, but it **uses a cached location value** instead of real-time data. **The cached location value is updated by the device every 15 minutes.**

I think, that Geolocator uses same API. I have start my test app, and it was returning same location for 15 minutes, after that it returned new location ( that i have set immediately after first location track done by scheduled agent).

**For testing i was using this code:**

```
#if DEBUG_AGENT
            ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
#endif
```

**Scheduled agent has interval in 30 minutes**, that's why behavior of location tracking will be norm without this code for testing.